# React Navigation Error this.props.navigation.navigat

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have two screens and I want to on click to move new screen using react navigation. but I got an error

> this.props.navigation.navigate

here is my code. anyone knows what is an issue. I follow every step.

```
    import React, {Component} from 'react';
    import { AppRegistry, View, Text,StyleSheet, TextInput, Image, ScrollView, Button, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
    import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';

    import SignUp from './SignUp';

    class Login extends  React.Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = { text: 'Useless Placeholder' };
    }
        render(){
    const {navigate} = this.props.navigation;
       return(
          <View>
              <ScrollView showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>
                <View style={styles.button}>
                         <TouchableOpacity>
                            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>SIGN IN</Text>
                          </TouchableOpacity>
                       </View>
                        <View style={styles.createAccount}>
                             <Text style={styles.createText}
                             onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("Home")}
                             >Create new account</Text>
                        </View>
               </View>
            </ScrollView>
          </View>

       );
    }

}


module.exports = Login;


const MainNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Home: {screen: SignUp}
});

export default createAppContainer(MainNavigator);
```

Comment: what type of errors is just `this.props.navigation.navigate` ? Can you provide the full message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Login screen is not a part of your stack.

```
const MainNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Home: {screen: SignUp}
});
```

Just make a **separate component of Login** screen add it on the top of your stack then you are able to navigate.

like this

```
const MainNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Login:{screen:Login}
  Home: {screen: SignUp}
});
```

**Login.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, View, Text,StyleSheet, TextInput, Image, ScrollView, Button, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';

    export default class Login extends  React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = { text: 'Useless Placeholder' };
    }
        render(){
    const {navigate} = this.props.navigation;
       return(
          <View>
              <ScrollView showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>
                <View style={styles.button}>
                         <TouchableOpacity>
                            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>SIGN IN</Text>
                          </TouchableOpacity>
                       </View>
                        <View style={styles.createAccount}>
                             <Text style={styles.createText}
                             onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("Home")}
                             >Create new account</Text>
                        </View>
               </View>
            </ScrollView>
          </View>

       );
    }
```

**MainNavigator.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
    import { AppRegistry, View, Text,StyleSheet, TextInput, Image, ScrollView, Button, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
    import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';

import SignUp from './SignUp';
import Login from './Login'


const MainNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Login: {screen:Login},
  Home: {screen: SignUp}
});

export default createAppContainer(MainNavigator);
```

Comment: just give 
login:{screen:Login}

Comment: i am in Login Component. then how to do this ?

Comment: @zeeshan Are you trying to go from login to signup as per your code right?

Comment: @ParasKorat yes

Comment: @zeeshan just try as I mentioned in my answer and your root file is MainNavigator.js

Comment: @ParasKorat now i got error. check the render method of 'APP'

Comment: @zeeshan are you able to navigate on next screen ? and one more this also change your onPress method is you using `const {navigate} = this.props.navigation` then  change it to`<Text style={styles.createText}
                             onPress={() =>navigate("Home")}
                             >Create new account</Text>`

Comment: @ParasKorat my root file is APP.js and i am using splash screen on load then redirect into Login screen

Comment: @ParasKorat not able to navigate. i make your changes

Comment: @zeeshan can you please add your file structure with the code so I'll help you in better way

Comment: src -> Home -> Login.js,SignUp.js, MainNavigator.js
and App.js on main file\

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191725/discussion-between-paras-korat-and-zeeshan).

Answer (score 1):

you haven't added your Login screen in stack 
here like this

```
const MainNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Login : {screen: Login},
  Home: {screen: SignUp}
});
```